# How do could you get specific blocks of data from a JSON array Swiftui

Tags: arrays, json, swiftui

I haven't written any code yet but I have a JSON which I want to get a specific block of data from to display on a very rudimentary view. I just want to grad a block of data that is nested in a JSON. Is there method for doing such a thing simply with swiftui? Im a beginner at Swiftui.

Comment: Is this a JSON string, or JSON from an API?

Comment: JSON from an API

Comment: You can grab the whole JSON, decode it, then get what you need

Comment: But how to grab a specific block of data, that is keyed?

Comment: That’s more a question about REST vs GraphQL APIs

Answer (score 1):

## Decoding/getting the data

There are multiple ways to access specific blocks of data from JSON data.
If you fetch your JSON object from an API, you'll likely need to decode it (`Data` type to custom type).

### First method: using SwiftyJSON

There is a great library to access specific parts of a JSON object which is called [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).
They provide a few examples like this one:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}
```

### Second method: using pure Swift

You have to serialize your JSON object and afterwards, you can access a specific block using:

```
if let statusesArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]],
    let user = statusesArray[0]["user"] as? [String: Any],
    let username = user["name"] as? String {
    // Finally we got the username
}
```

#### Third method: using custom Structs and Enums

The last method is to create a data model and parse your JSON. To create your data model you can use an app called [quicktype](https://quicktype.io).
You can then decode simply. [Here's a link to show you how](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-json-into-swift-objects-using-codable).

## Using/displaying the data

After decoding the data, you can parse it to an [`ObservableObject`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects) and loop through it using a [`List`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) or a [`ForEach`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach).

Comment: If this solved your issue/got you to understand, could you please mark this answer as the right one please?